# compare function in next_permutation for n-queen

Tags: c++, stl, permutation, n-queens

I'm trying to solve the n-queen problem using the inbuilt next_permutation function in c++ STL.
as in n queen, a valid permutation is the one, in which the previous queen shouldn't be adjacent to current, i.e. the abs(current_queen_index - prev_queen_index) != 1
I tried to create a compare function for the same, but it's not returning anything.

```
bool isValid(int cur_pos, int prev_pos) {
    return ( abs(cur_pos - prev_pos) != 1 );
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    do {
        cout<<v[0]<<" "<<v[1]<<" "<<v[2]<<" "<<v[3]<<"\n";
    } while( next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end(), isValid));

}
```

Comment: "but it's not returning anything" what you mean?..

Answer (score 2):

Last parameter is a compare function, not a `isValid`.

If you use `std::next_permutation`, you might check the full permutation.

```
bool isNotValid(int cur_pos, int prev_pos) {
    return std::abs(cur_pos - prev_pos) == 1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    do {
        if (std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), &isNotValid) == v.end()) {
            std::cout<<v[0]<<" "<<v[1]<<" "<<v[2]<<" "<<v[3]<<"\n";
        }
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/278bef0caa2e49f6)

Notice that that check for valid permutation works for size 4, but is wrong in general.

Comment: Great, I got your solution but is there any way to do it alone with next_permutaion, or any other better or more efficient way, where I don't need to generate the full list of permutation

Comment: I would not use permutation, but using backtracking.